# For which $0\leq a<p^2$, where $p$ is an odd prime, we have that $(2p-1)!\equiv a\mod{p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Let $p$ be an odd prime. I need to find for which $0\leq a < p^2$, $(2p-1)!\equiv a\mod{p^2}$.

If $a\equiv (2p-1)!\mod{p^2}$, then we have that $a = kp^2 + (2p-1)!$, and therefore $p\mid a$, which means $a$ is an integer multiple of $p$, and necessarily not zero, since we have only one instance of $p$ in $(2p-1)!$

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Have you worked any examples?  What do you get if $p=3,5,7$?

Comment: Why "odd"? How is $p=2$ different from the odd primes in this problem? (It isn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have $(2p-1)! = \prod_{i=1}^{2p-1} j =p \prod_{j=1}^{p-1}j(j+p)$. 
Thus modulo $p^2$ this is $p \prod_{j=1}^{p-1}j^2= p ((p-1)!)^2$.

Now one knows that $(p-1)!$ is congruent $-1$ modulo $p$; this is not hard to to show, and you can find it as part of a proof of Wilson's theorem.

Thus in total we get that the result is $p$.

Comment: You got that $(2p-1)! \equiv p((p-1)!)^2\mod{p^2}$, but this does not necessarily mean that $(2p-1)!\equiv p\mod{p^2}$. For example, $(7-1)!^2 \equiv 29\mod{49}$.

Comment: @Joshhh - you must use the fact that the RHS already has a factor of $p$ in it. In your counter-example, it doesn't. Don't ask quid to do ALL the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$
(p-1)! \equiv \frac{(2p-1)!}{p!} \equiv -1 \pmod p
$$
by [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) (edit: the division in the above expression is *regular integer division*, not modular division). So $\frac{(2p-1)!}{p} \equiv 1\pmod p$, or in other words, there is a $k$ such that
$$
\frac{(2p -1)!}{p} = kp + 1.
$$Multiply both sides by $p$ to get $a = p$.

Comment: How did you come up with your first statement?

Comment: The OP is right. What do you mean by "dividing by $p!$" modulo $p$???

Comment: @mathguy What I meant was "Take the three integers $x = (p-1)!, y = \frac{(2p-1)!}{p!}$ and $z = 1$. We have $x \equiv y \equiv z \pmod p$". The division is regular integer division, since $\equiv$ is a relation on the integers, after all. Apparently it was not as clear as I thought it was.

Comment: @Joshhh We have $n \equiv n+p\pmod p$, so $p! \equiv (p+1)\cdot (p+2)\cdots(2p-1) = \frac{(2p-1)!}{p!}$. Or $_{2p-1}P_{p}$ if you prefer that notation.

Comment: @Arthur Crystal clear. What is the notation you used $_{2p-1}P_p$?

Comment: @Joshhh It's a combinatorial notation you learn in some countries. It's a close relative to the binomial coefficient $_nC_r = \binom{n}{r}$, and it's just a shorthand: $_nP_r = \frac{n!}{r!}$. But writing $_{2p-1}P_p$ would've made it clearer that I was talking about the _integer_ $\frac{(2p-1)!}{p!}$ instead of the congruency class $(2p-1)!$ modulo $p$ divided by $p!$ (which, as pointed out by mathguy, doesn't make sense).